# How to add jQuery to glassfish

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish

Okay, this sounds stupid but this is driving me nuts.

I have been working with glassfish for the past few days and I decided to include jQuery and some css files to the glassfish project. Which is easy: I just copied jQuery-1.7.2.min.js and other css files to the project folder and linked them in .jsp, .html or .xhtml.

But that is not working.

I have tried to include by relative path and absolute path and .jsp, .html or .xhtml refuse to recognize that jquery file or css files.

Am I supposed to add js and css files in a special way in glassfish?

My pages are under /WebContent and js folder is under /WebContent/WEB-INF.

[image]

Comment: Post just one of the jsp or html to verify.Also post the folder structure.

Comment: @Pointy Could you tell me where it should go than?

Comment: Just put it in some folder outside of WEB-INF, and it'll be visible externally. The whole point of WEB-INF is that the only way it can be accessed is via servlet-mapped URLs.

Comment: @Pointy you were right and also I have forgotten that URL is case sensitive in this case...  I feel silly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the folders end up in the deployed webapp folder. This will depend on your build system. In a maven layout, that means you'll put them in src/main/webapp and they'll get copied their when you deploy.